# Moving wordpress site from Nginx to Dedicated Server Windows

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx, server

Can someone please let me know what should i do to transfer my current wordpress website from shared hosting in gninx server to a private dedicated Windows server?

The server is ready I just have to transfer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is using Microsoft Web Platform.

Before you install WordPress with Microsoft Web Platform, ensure that the following prerequisites are in place on your Windows system.
WordPress prerequisites: http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Microsoft WebMatrix and Microsoft Web Platform Installer (Web PI) are two very effective tools from Microsoft that automate the installation of WordPress. With these tools, you have the option to install not only Microsoft-based Web components but also a huge set of open source applications and built-in templates. Both these tools can be used to successfully install and host WordPress on a Windows-based system in order to create, publish and maintain your websites. These tools install the latest components of the Microsoft Web Platform including Internet Information Services (IIS), SQL Server Express, .NET Framework and Visual Web Developer.

To host a site from a Windows-based system using WordPress, you will need to install one of the following tools and use it to download and install WordPress and all the other required applications. Given below are the basic guidelines for installing WordPress using these tools. Ensure that your system is connected to the Internet before starting the process. You can also download all the required components offline and install WordPress. Using an online method with these tools is recommended, as it always fetches the data dynamically and allows you to install the latest supported components.

First WP based step is migration of your website root directory.

For me, the easiest way to do it is to install [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin. It wraps your site in the zip and you just need to upload the archive to your new server and follow the instructions (can be found at the link provided).

Also you should change your DNS and nameserver entries, between your domain and the servers.

Comment: I made some research and i found that i have to install first php,wordpress and sql to server. Is that right or should i just transfer?

Comment: Read edited answer, couple of ways is to use WebMatrix or Microsoft Web Platform.